# Configurable exporter - custom identity for the document

Tags: nlp, gate

While exporting an annotated document, I'm unable to set an identifier to the doc so that I can reference it for further usage within the gate ide. Is this possible? My use case involves parsing multiple documents and hence indexing would be ideal

Comment: Can you add more details about what do you want to achieve? E.g. give some example... How do you want to reference the doc and why?

Comment: Could you please clarify how you want to export document? GATE XML? Or?

Comment: So my use case demands parsing multiple documents at a time. Therefore I need to assign each "parsed" doc an ID. I want to use Configurable exporter in Annie using the dev ide. I want to export it as a csv.

Answer (score 0):

In case of export as GATE XML you could add a feature to Document Features.

```
doc.getFeatures().put("feature","value");
```

Exported result will be:

```
<GateDocumentFeatures>
<Feature>
<Name className="java.lang.String">feature</Name>
<Value className="java.lang.String">value</Value>
</Feature>
```